# ./prog.go:41:11: invalid character literal (more than one character)

Tags: go, variables, constants

I am new to Go language i just started learning by doing, but while running this code, im getting
the error as:
**a./prog.go:41:11: invalid character literal (more than one character)**

```
package main
import ("fmt")

func main() {

  const NAME = "Michael"
  const(
  age int = 22
  color = 'Fair'
  )

  fmt.Println(NAME)
  fmt.Println(age)
  fmt.Println(color)
  
}
```

Comment: `'` is for a single rune literal, `Fair` has 4 runes. Use `"` like `"Fair"`.

Answer (score 0):

In the above code, you are using single quotes for color variable value, that is what causing this error, try changing it to double quotes as below:

color = "Fair"

this should work.

Answer (score 0):

(Not only) for Go, it can be a good exercise to have open the [Go Reference Specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Rune_literals), as it is quite short and written for the language user. Here is what the official rules say about "runes" and "strings":

> #### Rune Literals
>
> A rune literal represents a rune constant, an integer value identifying a Unicode code point. A rune literal is expressed as one or more characters **enclosed in single quotes**, as in `'x'` or `'\n'`.

For strings:

> #### String Literals
>
> [there are two types, raw and interpreted string literals!]
>
> Raw string literals are character sequences between back quotes, as in `` `foo` ``. [...]
>
> Interpreted string literals are character sequences between double quotes, as in `"bar"`.

It can be handy to browse through the surrounding paragraphs to discover more rules and possible gotchas that one might encounter when coming from other languages.